# Palestinian Troop Strength During 1948 War

Tags: military, palestine

I am trying to estimate the strength of the Palestinian irregular forces during the [1947-49 War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1947%E2%80%931949_Palestine_war).

I find two well documented groups:

1. Army of the Holy War, commanded by Husayni, based in Ramalla,
   operating in Jerusalem Area size: ~1400
2. Arab Liberation Army, commanded by Qawuqji, Based in Damascus,
   operating in North size: 6000 (many of these were not Palestinians)

I would expect to find another main group based in the coastal area, which had a large population, but cannot find it.

Is this accurate, that there was only a maximum of ~7500 irregular Palestinian fighters (disregarding the trope that there is no such thing as a Palestinian)?

Comment: Hmmm, not quite as trivial as I thought it would be to look up. Upvoting. I will add that I found the ALA # is disputed. It may more properly be as low as 3,500.

Comment: Your terminology is anachronistic. In 1948 the word "Palestinian" meant a ***Jew*** living in Palestine, **not** an Arab.  The term "Palestinian people" was appropriated to mean Arabs only in 1960-ies.